# How can I de-duplicate code without declaring an additional function in C/C++?

Tags: c++, templates, chess

I am developing a chess engine and am working on move generation. For example, here is my function for generating moves for the black knight:

```
/** Pseudolegal moves don't take check into account. */
std::vector<uint8_t>
generate_pseudolegal_bknight_moves(std::shared_ptr<Position> position,
                                   uint8_t square) {
  assert(VALID_SQUARE(square));
  assert(position->mailbox[square] == B_KNIGHT);

  uint8_t candidates[8] = {
      NEXT_RANK(PREV_FILE(PREV_FILE(square))),
      NEXT_RANK(NEXT_RANK(PREV_FILE(square))),

      PREV_RANK(PREV_FILE(PREV_FILE(square))),
      PREV_RANK(PREV_RANK(PREV_FILE(square))),

      NEXT_RANK(NEXT_FILE(NEXT_FILE(square))),
      NEXT_RANK(NEXT_RANK(NEXT_FILE(square))),

      PREV_RANK(NEXT_FILE(NEXT_FILE(square))),
      PREV_RANK(PREV_RANK(NEXT_FILE(square))),
  };
  std::vector<uint8_t> moves;

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    uint8_t candidate = candidates[i];
    uint8_t piece = position->mailbox[candidate];
    if (VALID_SQUARE(candidate) && (!IS_BLACK_PIECE(piece))) {
      moves.push_back(candidate);
    }
  }

  return moves;
}
```

The function for generating white knight moves is very similar, with only two terms (macros) changing:
`B_KNIGHT` -> `W_KNIGHT`, and `IS_BLACK_PIECE` -> `IS_WHITE_PIECE`.

I'd prefer not to essentially duplicate the move generation function for every piece, but have been doing it this way so far because it has the smallest runtime overhead.
I could include `bool is_white` or something in the args and switch terms with a ternary `is_white ? W_KNIGHT : B_KNIGHT`, but the conditional would add an overhead during runtime that wasn't there previously, and it doesn't seem that elegant. I was wondering if there is some compile-time feature that would help me have one function definition.

I suppose I also could use inline functions to try and reduce the amount of duplicated code, but I was wondering if there was any alternative better than that.

Comment: Why don't you want an additional function? Or an if statement? What run-time overhead do you think that's going to introduce?

Comment: Can you detail exactly what tremendous overhead you fear, with modern multi-Ghz CPUs? But, in any case, if you're set in figuring out a way to have two functions but only a single instance of the shown logic, this happens to be exactly what templates are for, in C++. Do you know what templates are, and how you use them? Simply make the piece color a template parameter, and, there you go: two functions for the price of one!

Comment: Humans are generally bad at guessing what will make the code faster or slower. Old theories about Big-O notation regarding algorithmic complexity often get blown away by cache considerations and CPU pipelining. In short, you should not worry so much about the performance up front. Worry about correctness, and then use a profiler periodically to measure performance and determine where to focus speedup efforts. For instance, consider using a causal profiler like [Coz](https://github.com/plasma-umass/coz), a hotspot profiler like Intel vTune, gprof, etc., or a cache profiler like kcachegrind.

Comment: Every bit of overhead counts because these functions will get executed millions if not billions of times. Also I should mention that it's a personal project for learning, so of course some microscopic overhead is ultimately inconsequential. However, I am interested in figuring out how to do this with the intent of applying the pattern elsewhere.

Comment: You're very much going down the "straining out the gnat while swallowing the camel" path. Profile-based optimization on the target platform is the only sure way to make code faster. Branch prediction in modern processors is quite good, and you should not assume you know what "faster" even means at the CPU execution level without measurements. Otherwise you're just guessing and likely guessing wrongly.

Comment: @metal Don't get me wrong, I will most definitely be using a profiler. I agree with the overall sentiment of your message to not agonize over minuscule performance gains, and to not assume that changes made with the intention of optimization are going to be successful. 

I asked the question for this scenario in particular because I had an intuition that there was an elegant way to achieve what I was looking for. Kostas answer happened to be exactly that.

Comment: But half the text of your question is about the overhead concerns, and you haven't mentioned anywhere that you're looking for elegant code.

Comment: You're right, I should have emphasized that more in my question.

Comment: Well, then you should edit it now. As it stands the accepted answer is not really appropriate for the question.

Comment: The allocations in your return value will blow away the branching costs you are worried about.  Heck, your use of shared ptr might (atomic inc/decs). You need to write correct versions, write unit tests using those, implement a profiling framework, *then* worry about microptimization.  Because right now, you are micro-optimizing the wrong stuff.  Micro-optimizing the wrong stuff is harmful (not just "faster is better"), as increased code complexity makes optimizing the right stuff harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want overhead you can use a template parameter and `if constexpr`:

```
enum class Color { WHITE, BLACK };

template <Color C> std::vector<uint8_t>
generate_pseudolegal_knight_moves(std::shared_ptr<Position> position,
                                  uint8_t square) {
  ...
  if constexpr (C == Color::WHITE) {
    assert(position->mailbox[square] == W_KNIGHT);
  } else {
    assert(position->mailbox[square] == B_KNIGHT);
  }
  ...
}

// Call
auto moves = generate_pseudolegal_knight_moves<Color::WHITE>(...);
```

The standard guarantees the condition will be evaluated on compile time, and the false branch will be discarded.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, 

Comment: @vasia How do you know that? Have you tested it out, and compared it with your own version? Please don't assume you'll generate faster code without testing it.

Comment: @cigien This is what I was *looking* for. Whether or not it ends up being faster or not, is a separate question.